# What happens when my app reaches the Prospective Search Subscriptions quota?

Tags: google-app-engine

Can Google replenish this resource? 
If so, how are subscriptions billed when over quota? Costs?
Anyone else using it for a real life large scale app? (tens or thousands of users/subcriptions?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New subscriptions will fail when over the subscription quota.
Other quota is still in play but this is a hard ceiling right now.

So, at the time of this writing, unless you plan to keep your number of subscriptions under 10k, you are hosed.

Prospective search is great and I can't wait for it to finally come out of experimental status.

Comment: Can you please add some reference to the billing information of Prospective Search ? Is is the same as Search API ? oh, and what is "hosed" ?

Comment: I did a quick search but could not find where this is documented. However, I have an app running right now where I initially tried to use prospective search for alerting. It has 10k prospective search subscriptions and the quota details in the app console tell me it is maxed out.
Please excuse the colloquial English. "hosed" means "it doesn't work" or "you are out of luck".

Comment: I should add that I did ask to have the quota increased for prospective search subscriptions on this particular app but never received a response. 
Until Google makes prospective search production, I am working on my own solution (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/prospectivesearch/overview#Using_Prospective_Search):

The life of a typical prospective search application looks something like this:

1. You decide on the appropriate document schema. Your choice will depend on the type of source data that the application is designed to handle.
2. The application uses the subscribe() call to register query subscriptions with prospective search using the query language.
3. The application converts items in the streaming source data into documents, which are instances of db.Model.
4. Theapplication uses the match() call to present documents to prospective search for matching against subscribed queries.
5. Prospective search returns matching subscription IDs and documents in the task queue. These results are subject to the usual Quotas and
   Limits.

Based on that, looks like you are only subjected to the quotas limiting Task Queues, which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Task_Queue).